# How to make VS Code not open a terminal when debugging?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I've installed VS Code on Ubuntu 17.04.

When I debug my C++ application, the output is displayed in a dedicated terminal and not within VS Code itself (like Eclipse does).

How do I make VS Code display output within the editor itself, i.e., not open another terminal?

My launch configuration is as follows:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gdb",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/a.out",
            "args": ["foo", "bar", "baz"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "g++"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd hoped that setting `externalConsole` to false would solve the problem. However, it didn't change anything.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Please let me know if you found the answer.

Answer (score 2):

For a C++ project, use `"externalConsole": false,` as follows:

[image]

This will open integrated terminal instead of external terminal. You can use `"internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"` if you want to open the debug console instead of the integrated/external console:

[image]

For a Java project, use , `"console": "integratedTerminal"` in the configurations file:

[image]

Use `"console": "internalConsole"` if you do not want to see any debug console.

Answer (score 0):

Set `"console":"none"` like such:

```
"name": "Python: Current File",
"type": "python",
"request": "launch",
"program": "${file}"
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
"console": "none"
```